# Writing to a file in java by user input

Tags: java

How do i write text in file java. I have 10 rows, and i wanna write for each row?  I did this so far

```
    String filename ="data.txt";
    PrinterWriter output= new PrintWriter ( new FileWriter(filename, true));
    System.out.println("Please enter the student's data: ");
```

I want the user to add students for each students ( i want them to add their first name, studetn number, gender, their year, birthday, maybe phone number 2 and time table.) I don't know how to do that

Comment: It's the same as writing to the console.  You just need to write some more code and see how you go with your homework.

Comment: how would i do for every row? cuz my teacher only taught us to write like names

Comment: create `student` object assign all values to this object and then add them to`List`, use this `List` when you want to put the data in file

Comment: can i do this assign the user input to the specific row, for example if the user input student' last name it would go to row[0]?

Comment: When dealing with multiple rows you generally need a loop.  Hopefully your can lookup how to use a loop, even if your teacher hasn't covered them.  The specific details depend on how exactly the data is entered and how it has to be represented.  Note: we can't just give you an answer, because with homework it is important to give the *expected* answer based on what has been taught, which we don't know.

Comment: @PeterLawrey i can't find anything i am confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already created the Writer object all you need to do is to write to the file. If you have stored elements in some array or Arraylist then just do `pw.println()` in a loop. In order to accept user Input take a look on [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class E.g.

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WriteToFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt"));

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter n to finish");
        String text = "";
        while (!text.equals("n")) {
            System.out.println("enter first name");
            text = scanner.next();
            pw.write(text + ",");
            System.out.println("enter last name");
            text = scanner.next();
            pw.write(text + ",");
            System.out.println("enter sex");
            text = scanner.next();
            pw.write(text);
            //add more fields
            //finally
            pw.println();
            System.out.println("Continue?");
            text = scanner.next();
        }
        pw.close();
        System.out.println("completed");
    }
}
```

Comment: however i want the user to input that, the information i gave u was like the data

Comment: I want the user to add students for each students ( i want them to add their first name, studetn number, gender, their year, birthday, maybe phone number 2 and time table.) I don't know how to do that. Just like the data i gave on teh post

Comment: is there an easy way to do this? ik u did alot of work cuz i don't understand and my teacher will ask me lots of questions on this

Comment: can i do this using for loop?

Comment: @Pokemonmaster i haven't played much with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this: Create a hashmap for the student data `HashMap<StudentData>` and put all the user input into the HashMap. If you do not want any `key` to recognize data, I'd use `Vector<StudentData>`

Once you have collected all the data, iterate through the HashMap/Vector and write it to the file.

To write to the file, you need to use `write`

```
public void writeData()
{
FileWriter output=  new FileWriter("data.txt", true);

// iterate through hashmap/vector and store value in a variable or just write directly

ouput.write(value);
output.close();

}
```

Comment: Can you explain what exactly are you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: Well, it would be difficult to do it line by line. If users presses return key, you need to write the data and there would be too many write command. I'd recommend figure out a way to store the data in some variable and then write it.